# How do I prevent the scraping that occurs when I rotate my leg about my hip?

Tags: stretching, legs, yoga, parkour, hip

I recently started taking parkour lessons and after a full day of vaulting and jumping around, the area around my hip flexor (or possible the hip flexor itself, I'm not a doctor) hurts. For some reason, it seems to only happen to my right leg (probably because of a tendency to vault a certain way based on right-handedness). When I stand on my left leg and then lift and rotate my right leg, it feels like a tendon being caught on something. Sometimes after a few rotations or stretching, the feeling will go away (though the soreness remains) but then return again later.

I'm trying my best not to fall into the trap of trying to self-diagnose with the internet and I can't afford a doctor for the time being, so I'm hoping to find some advice here. Is anyone familiar with the feeling I'm describing? How can I treat and prevent it?

Attempting to push my knees down while in the butterfly position causes a feeling of tightness (of both legs) in the same spot and I believe it may be similar to what [the poster of a similar question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1462/why-is-my-outer-hip-tight-when-doing-some-inner-thigh-stretches) experiences.

Comment: You go see a physiotherapist.

Answer (score 0):

'Tight hips' or limited hip mobility are a common problem for people who do a lot of sitting (e.g. office drones, like me). I have not exactly the same problem you do, but something similar involving a tendon by my left hip.

Limited mobility does not necessarily mean you *can't* make a movement. It's an umbrella term which can also describe your experience of having trouble while moving in a certain range of the joint.

My problems diminished greatly when I started doing targeted hip mobility exercises. [This page has several drills, videos, and an explanation.](https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/blog/exercise-type/dynamic-warm-up-exercises/hip-mobility-drills/) HOWEVER. Mobility drills cannot solve everything: sometimes a tendon or muscle is attached under a non-ideal angle. If gently increasing the drills do not solve your problem, you really should contact a physical therapist and have them check the alignment of your hip area.