# Is there a chance to develop lotus position during adulthood?

Tags: flexibility, hip

I'm 27 and I've never stayed in lotus position my whole life, now I'm trying because I find it the best position for meditation, but I'm very inflexible. I read somewhere that it's too late to develop a lotus position at this stage but I think that if I develop proper stretching specially hip openers I can get it.

is there any step by step method to follow to get that ?

Comment: You may find some of the information at https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/how-to-safely-approach-the-lotus-position-for-someone-with-tight-hips interesting, although the answer more or less weighs toward "if you sit a lot, probably not".

Comment: Have you ever tried hot yoga? I'm convinced that the sauna-like atmosphere loosens me up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an authoritative source, but yes, you can likely learn to do the lotus position even as an adult. Typing *lotus position progression* into Google gets you a number of poses and positions to work up to a full lotus. Here are a few:

[Five Poses to prepare your for Lotus](https://yoga.com/article/5-poses-to-prepare-you-for-lotus):

> - Bound Angle Pose (Baddha Konasana)
> - Revolved Head to Knee Pose (Parivrivritta Janu Sirsasana)
> - Pigeon (Eka Pada Rajakapotasana)
> - Cow Face Pose (Gomukhasana)
> - Half lotus pose (Ardha Padmasana)

[How to Lotus: a Guide for the Inflexible](https://www.elephantjournal.com/2014/10/how-to-lotus-a-beginners-guide-for-the-inflexible/)

> - Exercise 1: Foot to Thigh
> - Exercise 2: Butterfly
> - Exercise 3: Elevated Butterfly

There are also video tutorials out there, but that would require me to transcribe the contents and I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to check [Stretch Therapy](https://stretchtherapy.net/) from Kit Laughlin. He is one of the best person I know for improving flexibility as an adult.

Nice forums, nice resources, nice vimeos. Everything at a reasonable price. I even would like to attend one of his seminars in Europe one day.